# Open tool subscriber change mirror property after starting connection

Tags: tokbox

Good day do you know if is possible to change the mirror propierty when some subscriptor switching between cameras

Answer (score 0):

You would need to unpublish with `session.unpublish(publisher)` followed by `publisher.destroy();`, and then republish with the new publisher options, including the new camera device id and updated mirror option.